# What's the full range of supported Google Docs LaTeX macros?

Tags: google-docs, formatting, latex

Google Docs has an equation editor that has a fair number of options for symbols and functions available from the dropdown menu. All of these are also available through LaTeX macros that are conveniently listed<sup>†</sup> at [Google Docs Support: Mathematical equations](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/160749). However, this list is not complete. Some of the common amsmath functions that also work include:

- `\underline`
- `\hat`
- `\bar`
- `\min`
- `\max`

Is there a list of all of the supported macros?

---

<sup>†</sup> Not at present, but Wayback Machine has a copy: https://web.archive.org/web/20160409034821/https://support.google.com/docs/answer/160749?hl=en