# How to insert TeX code in a Google Document?

Tags: google-docs

I see that you can insert equations, but I would love to have the freedom of TeX, all mathematics symbols.

Is there any way to insert e.g. `$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} $$` and it parses it?

Answer (score 4):

No, Google Documents do not contain a LaTeX parser.  There is a limited support for [TeX macros](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/160749), mostly for characters: you can type `\int` followed by a space and get the integral sign; then type `^` and get superscript, etc. To use the full power of LaTeX, you need a LaTeX processor, which Google Docs is not.

By the way, the documentation to which I linked appears to be outdated:  Docs support more than is listed there ([examples](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/80124/79865)). The only way to know for sure what's there is to try a command. Just remember that Docs requires space after command, and does not use {} grouping, relying instead on Word-type maneuvers like "Tab to go from numerator to denominator".

Comment: I needed especially \frac, \vec, \sqrt and some more would be [tex-awesome](http://www.echteinfach.tv/tools/tex/). Thanks for your information.

Comment: Those three are supported, even though I don't see \vec listed in the documentation. It seems that documentation is outdated, and Docs support more than is listed there ([examples](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/80124/79865)). The only way to know is to try a command, remembering that Docs requires space after command, and does not use {} grouping.

Comment: Okay, just now I see that you have to do >Insert >Equation and then the commands above work. I tried it directly in the document at first. Thanks for the infos. Now it would be great to know a shortcut to bring up the equation.

Comment: LaTeX is a macro package that is an add-on for raw TeX. The above answer does not make that distinction and thus does not really answer the question.